# Cookies expire return 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms, httpcookie

How to get cookie date expiration ? I used the following line code to getting it

```
Request.Cookies("CookieName").Expires.ToString()
```

always it return ( Expires: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM ) however I had set expire date to it.

```
varcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)
```

Comment: did you try this `Request.Cookies["CookieName"].Expires.ToString()`

Comment: yes I did, just return 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to check `Expires` (as well as `Domain` and `Path`) of `Cookie` object in `Request`. If `Request.Cookies["name"]` received it means that it is not expired and sent to correct domain and path.
In other words, a browser sends only "live" cookie's *name: value* pair.
In `Response.Cookies` you can set `Expires` date. The cookie survives until that expiration date or a moment one close a browser, whichever occurs **last**.

Comment: Thank you so much,I am agree with you just I want to get date of expiration of the cookies.